# Can't solve error regarding 'org.codeaurora.qcamera3.exposure_metering.exposure_metering_mode'

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore, android-camera2, sceneform

I am working on an android application with AR elements. When it is redirecting me from the onboarding screen to the AR screen it crashes with the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find tag for key 'org.codeaurora.qcamera3.exposure_metering.exposure_metering_mode')
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraMetadataNative.nativeGetTagFromKeyLocal(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraMetadataNative.setBase(CameraMetadataNative.java:1389)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraMetadataNative.set(CameraMetadataNative.java:459)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraMetadataNative.set(CameraMetadataNative.java:463)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Builder.set(CaptureRequest.java:848)
        at dez.a(PG:49)
        at gtf.g(PG:104)
        at det.a(Unknown Source:12)
        at gjw.e(PG:5)
        at gnx.run(PG:12)
        at gsa.run(PG:2)
        at gtc.run(PG:1)
        at gsw.f(PG:2)
        at gsv.run(PG:6)
        Suppressed: gnv: [gpc{Cancelling}@66fb9dc, Dispatchers.IO]
```

It works fine on android API level 31 and the crash only happens on **level 29**. Does anybody have any idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a device dependent problem and the issue is reported on ARCore github.
https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/1261

Comment: I'm not sure how this ended up in the VLQ queue, but this *is* an answer because even if you remove the link it still answers the question. Whether it's a *correct* answer or not is a matter for voting.